# Symfony 2 service with multiple instances?

Tags: php, symfony

I read this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

It said:

```
$mailer = $this->get('my_mailer');
```

> As an added bonus, the Mailer service is only created once and the
>   same instance is returned each time you ask for the service. This is
>   almost always the behavior you'll need (it's more flexible and
>   powerful), **but we'll learn later how you can configure a service that
>   has multiple instances.**

How do I make my service to have multiple instances -- i.e. whenever I reach the service I am given a new instance? Something like `$this->getNew()` or something?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are talking about the scope of a service. You can look them up [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container/scopes.html). In short, define your service as scope prototype instead of the default container and the dependency injection container will take care to create a new object every time you request it:

```
services:
    my_service:
        class: Someclass
        scope: prototype
```

Note: since Symfony2.8, `scope: prototype` has been replaced by `shared: false`.

```
# Symfony >= 2.8
services:
    my_service:
        class: Someclass
        shared: false
```

Comment: Is there a way to only force the re-creation sometimes not always?

Comment: @RezaSanaie You'd probably need to define an abstract service and extend that twice to have a prototype and container scoped version of it.  If you need to persist the new instance of the prototype you can override the container scoped one by setting the new instance to it.

Answer (score 7):

In Symfony >= 2.8 the scope attribute was deprecated and in version 3 removed. You need to use the shared setting as described here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/shared.html

Comment: can this be used in symfony 2.7?

Comment: Yes it was deprecated in 2.8.